# Adobe illustrator tracing in js script

Tags: adobe, trace, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to trace a PNG image in Adobe Illustrator via js script. I've tried different approaches, but always have the same problem - I can't change Color setting automatically. Here is my simple script:

```
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.tracingMethod = TracingMethodType.TRACINGMETHODABUTTING;
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.cornerFidelity = 50;
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.pathFidelity = 55;
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.noiseFidelity = 5;
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.maxColors = 40;
thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.colorFidelity = 50;
app.redraw();
```

So other parameters were changed during this script execution (Paths, Corners, Noise), but Colors is 100 again despite maxColors and colorFidelity. And I don't see any additional fields in tracing options that can be responsible for this.

[image]

Could you please give me any advise how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. What does this row mean: thisImage.tracing.tracingOptions.tracingMethod = TracingMethodType.TRACINGMETHODABUTTING; ?
   I could not find any property tracingMethod in TracingOptions in   [Adobe Illustrator CC Reference: JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html), p.233
2. From above mentioned doc for TracingOptions object: 
   maxColors:  The maximum number of colors allowed for automatic
   palette generation. Used only if tracingMode is color or grayscale. Range: 2 to 256

Hence, tracingOptions.tracingMode should be set to appropriate value. 
In your script this setting is absent.

Comment: 1. That's a tracing method: abutting or overlapping. Yes, there is no any notes about in the documentation but it affects the result. Of course, I've tried to remove this line. Nothing happens.
2. tracingMode color is the default value. So it's already set. But i've tried to set it forcibly - i had the same result.